# Application launch sequence Android and Apple

Tags: android, ios, performance

I've noticed that Android applications launch is a lot slower than in Apple iPhones. Android has this slight lag soon as you tap the icon to launch it and split second wait before the animation to launch the app begins. In iPhones, the animation begins instantly on tapping the icon.

I also noticed that when the app is saved in the Recent Apps in Android, it will launch instantly when resumed. It is almost identical to Apple launch speeds. But Apple has an edge because the app launches instantly regardless of whether it's in the recent apps.

My questions are:

1. How does the launch sequence differ between Android and Apple?
2. In Android, is there anything programatically in the app itself that can be done to improve launch speeds (ie. in the `onCreate` method)?

**UPDATE**
I've only ever programmed in Android Java, I've never touched Apple. Some inside programming knowledge on Apple would be helpful.

Comment: When an application is in the recent apps it is already started, initialized and in memory. Therefore it can be very fast. Delays when starting from scratch on home screen may be affected by other functions too, like the long click detection delay.

Comment: I see, so is there anything which may be done to improve this or is this down to lack of perfection of Android Firmware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications and processes may transition between several states:

- Active
- paused
- stopped
- inactive
- suspended

Callback methods allow applications to prepare for and respond to transitions.

**Android lifecycle methods**

- Lifecycle state transitions trigger event callback methods
- Callback events differ based on type of component(Callback methods take place in foreground and should be brief)

[image: Android Life Cycle]

**iOS Application LifeCycle**

UIApplication notified of state transition events
Handled by application delegate

- application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
- applicationDidBecomeActive:
- applicationWillResignActive:
- applicationDidEnterBackground:
- applicationWillEnterForeground:
- applicationWillTerminate:

For more info, have a look at this: Application Lifecycle "www.cse.nd.edu/~cmille17/teaching/cse40333/ApplicationLifecycle.pptx‎"

Let me know if you need further insight of iOS programming basics.. :)